# Django permissions in checkbox form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a template in which I edit all the basic fields of a model User.

Now I want to have a form in which there will be displayed all available permissions in a checkbox-like style. The ones already assigned to the User should already be checked.

I have a form.py, with a form for editing User, but have not completed the permissions form.

```
class UserSettingsForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = (
        'username',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'urnik',
        'ure_na_teden',
        'rfid',
        'oddelek',
        'status_zaposleni',
    )

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
    super(UserSettingsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    instance = getattr(self, 'instance', None)
    self.fields['username'].disabled = True

def save(self):
    user = super(UserSettingsForm, self).save()
    return user

class UserPermissonsForm(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Permission
    fields = (
        'name',
        'content_type',
        'codename',
    )
```

And a views.py:

```
@login_required
def uporabnik_uredi(request, username=None):
user = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
uporabnik_form = UserSettingsForm(request.POST or None,request=request, instance=user)
permissions = [(p.id, p.name) for p in Permission.objects.filter(user=user)]
data = {
    'uporabnik' : user,
    'form' : uporabnik_form,
    'from': request.GET.get('from', None),
    'permissions' : permissions,
}

if request.POST:
    if uporabnik_form.is_valid():
        user = uporabnik_form.save()
        next = request.GET.get('next', None)
        return redirect(next)
return render(request, "sifranti/uporabniki/uredi.html", data)
```

And also a template, just to see which current permissions are assigned to the user:

```
<div class="">
    {% for id, name in permissions %}
        {{ id }} - {{ name }} <br>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is how I do but i use a MultipleSelect, I guess you can apply some of this to checkboxes.

```
class EditUserForm(forms.ModelForm):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(EditUserForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_label(obj):
        permission_name = str(obj).split('|')[2].strip()
        model_name = permission_name.split(' ')[2].strip()
        return '%s | %s' % (model_name.title(), permission_name)

    User = get_user_model()
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(User)
    self.fields['user_permissions'].queryset = Permission.objects.filter(content_type=content_type)
    self.fields['user_permissions'].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'permission-select'})
    self.fields['user_permissions'].help_text = None
    self.fields['user_permissions'].label = "Label"
    self.fields['user_permissions'].label_from_instance = get_label

def save(self, commit=True):
    user_instance = super(EditUserForm, self).save(commit)
    user_instance.save()
    user_instance.user_permissions.set(self.cleaned_data.get('user_permissions'))
    return user_instance

class Meta:
    model = get_user_model()
    fields = ['email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'user_permissions']

    widgets = {
        'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'width: 300px;'}),
        'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'width: 300px;'}),
        'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'style': 'width: 300px;'}),
        'user_permissions': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'style': 'width: 350px; height: 200px;'})
    }
```

Hope this helps, good luck!